# Javascript conserva datos datos viejos o de cache?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

Cuando ejecuto este codigo, me da un error en la variable Kilometraje_edit si pongo un valor similar a 100000 o cualquiera que sea un 1 y varios ceros, al imprimir en pantalla las variables y desde consola aparece que las varaibles si conservan los datos correspondientes pero en el if no realiza la tarea correcta, solo si en kilometro_edit agrego un valor que no inice con 1 realiza la tarea correctamente

```
function registroCompraEfectivo(){
        var kilometraje_actual = $("#kilometraje_ac").val();
        var Kilometraje_edit = $("#kilometraje").val();
        var kilometr= $("#kilometr").val();

        console.log(kilometraje_actual);
        console.log(Kilometraje_edit);
        console.log(kilometr);

        if(Kilometraje_edit>0){

            if( Kilometraje_edit >= kilometr){
             swal({
                              title: '¿Realmente quiere realizar la siguiente modificacion?',
                              text: "Va a cambiar el kilometraje actual: "+kilometraje_actual+"\n\r por el kilometraje: "+Kilometraje_edit+"\n\r Si no está seguro, por favor, cancele. De lo contrario, ¡confirme!",
                              type: 'warning',
                              showCancelButton: true,
                              confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                              cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                              confirmButtonText: 'Confirmar'
                            }).then((result) => {
                              if (result.value) {
                                swal(
                                  '¡Confirmado!',
                                  'Su pedido ha sido registrado con éxito.',
                                  'success'
                                )
                                $("#form_editar").submit();
                              }
                            });
            }else{
                swal({
                        type: 'error',
                        title: 'Error en el kilometraje',
                        text: 'El kilometraje especificado no puede ser menor a: '+kilometr+'km'+' y usted agrego: '+Kilometraje_edit,
                        showConfirmButton: true
                    })         
            }
        }else{
            swal({
                        type: 'error',
                        title: 'El kilometraje no puede ser 0',
                        showConfirmButton: true
                    })   
        }           

    };
```

Lo que el codigo deber hacer es simplemente alertar de que los datos proporcionados son menores que los datos anteriores y en caso de no ser así envia el formulario para realizar los querys

Comment: Ya encontré el error, el problema era que al traer los valores se mantenían como un tipo diferente a int, entonces al comparar las dos variables verificaba que, por ejemplo si tenia en kilometr = 500000 y en la otra variable Kilometraje_edit = 10000000 como 5 es mayor que 1 ya no ejecutaba correctamente el if, para solucionarlo convertí los calores a tipo int y todo funciono como debía

Answer (score 1):

al hacer esto:

```
kilometraje_actual=parseInt(kilometraje_actual);
Kilometraje_edit=parseInt(Kilometraje_edit);
kilometr=parseInt(kilometr);
```

el if ya reconoció los valores y arrojo los mensajes como era debido